# ios Google+ Sign In with GPPSignInButton

Tags: ios, google-plus, signing

I've integrated Google+ sign in using GPPSignInButton as per google's example.
However, when I click on the SignIn button I get redirected to Safari browser for authentication. Apple review board failed my app because of this claiming that I need to keep user inside the app and not redirect him to Safari.

Is there any way to do so with this GPPSignInButton?

Comment: Just tried the latest Instgram App, which has option to use Facebook login, it also behaves the same way. Maybe you can try to appeal with Apple.

Comment: +1 to what @DinoTw said. There are a number of applications performing authorization within a webview using GPPSignInButton.